# Is there a way to set DateTime.ToString() format globally?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know is there any way to set DateTime.ToString() format globally?

Lets say that I want all of my DateTime objects on my application to be formatted to "yyyy-MM-dd." I could've done it by calling .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") from each instances of the object. But I think that would not seem to be clean and elegant.

I could've just created a new class that inherits DateTime class and override the .ToString method, but I realized that DateTime is a sealed class which I cannot inherit and modify. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: What kind of application needs this change? Desktop app or Web application? (WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an extension method.

```
public static string ToSortableString(this DateTime datetime)
{
    return datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Comment: Make sure you declare the function inside a non-nested static function

Comment: Inside a non-nested static `class`

Answer (score 15):

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
      CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
      newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
      newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    }
```

change the current thread culture in your Global.asax file and it Should make it globally

Or

Set the Globalization in web.config as:

```
<system.web>
<globalization  culture="en-NZ"  uiCulture="en-NZ"/>
</system.web>
```

[List Of All Country Codes](http://timtrott.co.uk/culture-codes/)

Comment: Not bad but it will affect parsing and formatting as well. It is alright if this is what the OP wants.

Comment: Actually I suggested your Generic Extension Method to the OP but, he/she needs it globally so suggested this method @taffer

Comment: Sry I forgot to mention that I am creating console application not web application. Is this applicable to console application?

Comment: You just saved me a whole lot of pain. Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

Oh yeah.,i get your question and this is the best way to approach such a problem.
Create a class e.g

```
public class DateFormatter
{
    public DateFormatter()
       {
       }
 public string FormatDate(DateTime date)
 {
      return date.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
 }
}
```

Then create a static instance of this class in App.xaml.cs like this

```
public static DateFormatter formatter = new DateFormatter();
```

In your code you will just be calling this class in this format

```
textBox1.DataContext = App.formatter.FormatDate({your-datetime-variable});
```

Comment: This is not what I needed actually, I want to keep using the DateTime.ToString() method instead of creating a new method or new class. But thanks for the feedback!